# How to add rules in Url redirect in iis 10

Tags: iis

I want to write redirect rules in IIS 10. I googled it and spent half of my day figuring out but no luck so I am posting it to get some solution.

1. `https://testing.app.com/apptest` should redirect to `https://testing.app.com/apptest/account/login`
2. `https://testing.app.com/apptest/` should redirect to `https://testing.app.com/apptest/account/login`
3. `https://test-apptest.testing.app.com/` should redirect to `https://test-apptest.testing.app.com/account/login`
4. `https://test-apptest.testing.app.com` should redirect to `https://test-apptest.testing.app.com/account/login`

But when user types url `https://testing.app.com/apptest/account/login` or `https://test-apptest.testing.app.com/account/login` then it should not redirect anywhere and it should stay as it is.

```
      <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Test1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="account/login" />                   
                    <action type="None" />
                </rule>  
                <rule name="Test2">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="testing.app.com" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/apptest" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://testing.app.com/apptest/account/login" appendQueryString="false" />
                </rule>
                
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We just add an anchor point to the regular expression so that precisely matches the segment `‘/apptest’`.
**Updated**

```
  <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="MyRule1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^((/apptest)?)/?$" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{http_host}{C:1}/account/login" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

**Explanation**
Since the hostname changed and will subsequently be appended in the redirection URL, I replace it with `{http_host}` server variable to follow it. Besides, `{Request_URI}` will return the URL path and `{C:1}` will return either `"/apptest"` or `""`. therefore I append it into the redirection URL.
The meaning of every server variable.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference#accessing-url-parts-from-a-rewrite-rule

---

Finally, please don’t forget to install the URL Rewrite extension before applying the rules.
https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite
Here is a quick reference of the regular expression from Microsoft documentation.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference
Feel free to let me know if the problem persists.

Comment: Hi Abraham, your solution worked for me. Thank you so much. you almost saved my day. If the condition is either `https://testing.app.com/apptest` or `https://testing.app.com/apptest/`, still it should go to `https://testing.app.com/apptest/account/login`. How to achieve this one. Also appreciated if you could explain your answer so that in future i can try by myself in different condition. Thank you

Comment: @Abaraham, I have added some more scenarios in the above question. Appreciated, if you could provide me a solution for that as well. Thank you

Comment: @KeentoLearn, (^.^), sorry for the late response. try this, "^/apptest/?$".  ? means that matching the last element one or zero times.

Comment: Hi Abraham, can you please help me. When I type `https://test-google.com/` or `https://test-google.com` then it should redirect to `https://test-google.com/tt/pp`. I am trying this way: condition `{REQUEST_URI}` to `^((/test)?)/?$`. then redirect to `https://test-google.com/tt/pp`. But I am not getting into it. Please guide me where I am going wrong.